# Can I tell PyInstaller to package my entire source tree?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, python-3.5

Currently my PyInstaller spec looks like this:

```
import sys
import os
import re
from pathlib import Path

DEBUG = True

lib = Path("lib/alpha")

hidden_imports = []
hidden_imports += lib.glob("processes/**/*.py")
hidden_imports += lib.glob("ui/config_panels/**/*.py")
hidden_imports += lib.glob("ui/logic/**/*.py")
hidden_imports = list(str(x) for x in hidden_imports)

for index, path in enumerate(hidden_imports):
    path = re.sub(r"lib(\\|\/)", "", path)

    if "__init__.py" in path:
        path = re.sub(r"(\\|\/)__init__.py", "", path)
    else:
        path = re.sub(r"\.py", "", path)

    hidden_imports[index] = ".".join(re.split(r"\\|\/", path))

block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(
    ["app.pyw"],
    pathex=["lib"],
    binaries=None,
    datas=[
        ("icons/*", "icons")
    ],
    hiddenimports=hidden_imports,
    hookspath=None,
    runtime_hooks=None,
    excludes=None,
    win_no_prefer_redirects=None,
    win_private_assemblies=None,
    cipher=block_cipher
)

pyz = PYZ(
    a.pure, a.zipped_data,
    cipher=block_cipher
)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    name="alpha",
    debug=DEBUG,
    strip=None,
    upx=True,
    console=DEBUG,
    icon="icons\\foo.ico"
)
```

Ugly as hell, right?

I have some directories in my source tree with file names that follow a specific naming convention and are imported on demand using `importlib`. I don't want to hard-code the name of all those modules into my spec for obvious reasons.

When using the "hiddenimports" option, the argument has to be a list of module names, so I have to `glob` for file names, loop over the resulting list and "modulify" the file names, taking into consideration Windows and Linux support.

There has to be a better way. Is there some way I can tell PyInstaller to just include my *whole* source tree, i.e. every file under `lib/alpha`?

Answer (score 0):

You can include an entire directory tree using the [`Tree()` function](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#the-toc-and-tree-classes), but this will not do exactly what you want. Since you're adding source files, you will want PyInstaller to analyze them recursively for imports to make sure all of their dependencies are included. The best way to do that is via hiddenimports.

Rather than explain in detail, I'll just share a snippet from my own specfile, which I use to include modules that are not included directly by my app, but are provided for user-created plugins to use. That fits your use-case closely enough.

```
# Files under mcedit2.synth are used only by plugins and not internally.
support_modules = []
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(os.path.join('src', 'mcedit2', 'synth')):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.py'):
        if filename == "__init__.py":
            filepath = root
        else:
            filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
            filepath = filepath[:-3]  # discard ".py"

        components = filepath.split(os.path.sep)
        components = components[1:]  # discard 'src/'

        if "test" in components or components == ["mcedit2", "main"]:
            continue

        modulename = ".".join(components)  # dotted modulename
        support_modules.append(modulename)

hiddenimports.extend(support_modules)
```

Comment: Wait a second. I think I can just use `collect_submodules` for this. It's normally used by hookfiles to collect the submodules of an imported library, but it should be usable in the specfile too.